# Query does not work

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, foreach

I made this code:

```
  Acum, bifeaza materiile pe care le studiaza clasa aleasa:<br />
     <form name="servForm" action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
    <table border="0">
  <?php  
$a = 0;
        $rezultat = "SELECT id, materie
        FROM  materii
        ORDER BY id";

        $rezultat1 = mysql_query($rezultat);
        while($plm = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat1))
            {
            if($a++ %5 == 0) echo "<tr>";
            ?>
 <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="<?php echo $plm['id']; ?>" /></td>
            <td style="text-align:left"><?php echo $plm["materie"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <?php
        if($a %5 == 0) echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
<br/>

    <input type="reset" value="Sterge" /> <input type="submit" value="Salveaza" name="savebtn" />
    </form>


    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['savebtn']))
    {
     foreach($_POST["checkbox2"] as $loc_id)
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO materii_pe_clase(id_scoala,id_clasa,id_materie) VALUES('$scoalalui','$clasalui','$loc_id')"; //aici cauta ! :)) 
  $result5 = mysql_query($query)
  or die('eroare');

}//sfarsit foreact
     }//sfarsit if isset
```

Why does the last query not work? p.s. its a school project, so mysql is ok, no need for mysqli. p.p.s I defindet the $scoalalui and $clasalui somwhere a little up the page. but they are not the problem, i tried replacing them with values. the query simply does not work. thanks!

thank you all!

EDIT

VARDUMP for $clasalui and $scoalalui
:

```
string '1' (length=1)
string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? **Error messages, log entries, etc**.

Comment: Please define your "not work". If it gives an error, post that error. If it executes, please tell how the results are different from your expectations.

Comment: it does not add the values to the database. Nothing happens, it just returns my page to the first step of this form. nothing at all happens. no errors, nothing

Comment: @Fred, he mentioned that in his question.

Comment: Does your form use POST? Is it getting to the point in your code where it should be running the query? Have you checked the generated SQL?

Comment: @AcelasiEu next time please try not to add those sentences in code. You might get banned.

Comment: can you post the entire code ?

Comment: @JamieTaylor Yea just noticed, skimmed the last bit.

Comment: @Mihai ok Mihai Iorga. I didn`t know so many romanians are around here. Sorry. You edited it before me. thanks!

Comment: This code is a mess. Write proper code, use proper objects and libraries and you will easily be able to debug every single line. `mysql_error()`?? or `mysql_last_error()`?

Comment: @danfromgermany the problem is not the mysql. the problem is somewhere in the php. As I said already in the question, i tried replacing the variables from the query with values to no avail. I also tried the query in phpmyadmin and it works.

Comment: @andrewsi yes, it uses post, and it is getting to the foreach part, but it just dont work.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` all the values from the last query and give us the output of `mysql_` debug functions

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($_POST["checkbox2"])` before it enters the foreach to make sure that it's going to iterate through it, and also echo out the $query inside of the foreach to make sure it looks correct?  You also really should convert everything to PDO/mysqli since the mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. It will also let you use parameters, and avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @DanFromGermany when i get home i will var_dump the values, but they are not a problem(mysql is not a problem here), because i tested the script by replacing the variables from the query with values, and it does not work. I also tested the query in phpmyadmin sql and it works.

Comment: @AcelasiEu that's why you should dump the variables. I guess it's something like... variable is null,... column is not null allowed. Use the debug functions I told you it will help

Comment: sorry for the long time, there are a lot of earthquakes in my area (50 in the last week) so i moved... Will try the var dump and come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that, you have error tool turned off, because PHP should have said, something like this. 
`Notice: Undefined variable $PHP_SELF"`

Since you don't see it, I'd assume that, its a root of your "problem".

`PHP_SELF` is not a variable, that's a constant. Its not even required here, as by default PHP sends data to its target URL.

I improved readability of your code, so that should work for you now,

```
<?php

// You want to see all errors? Fine:
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$a = 0;
$rezultat = "SELECT id, materie FROM  materii ORDER BY id";
$rezultat1 = mysql_query($rezultat);


// If the form is submitted, this will be executed
if (isset($_POST['savebtn'])) {
    foreach($_POST["checkbox2"] as $loc_id) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO `materii_pe_clase` (`id_scoala`, `id_clasa`, `id_materie`) VALUES('$scoalalui', '$clasalui', '$loc_id')"; 

        $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query);

        if (!$result){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

    // And finally
    die('Saved. Thanks');
}
?>

 Acum, bifeaza materiile pe care le studiaza clasa aleasa: <br />

 <form name="servForm" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <?php while($plm = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat1)) : ?>

        <?php if ($a++ %5 == 0) :?>
        <tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="<?php echo $plm['id']; ?>" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left"><?php echo $plm["materie"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>

        <?php if($a %5 == 0) : ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </table>

    <br/>

    <input type="reset" value="Sterge" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salveaza" name="savebtn" />
 </form>
```